# Endogenous interaction terms as IV

Tags: interaction, instrumental-variables

I want to estimate $$y_i=\beta_0+\beta_1 X_{i1}*X_{i2}+\beta_2 X_{i1}+\beta_3 X_{i2}....+\epsilon_i$$

where
$X_{i1}*X_{i2}$: the instrument variable of what I want to estimate, continuous

$X_{i1}$: exogenous, continuous

$X_{i2}$: very likely to be endogenous, binary.

My concern is, if $X_{i2}$ is endogenous, wouldn't that means the interaction term $X_{i1}*X_{i2}$ is not exogenous as well and can't be used as instrument variable?

Comment: Your intuition is correct. You can usually verify things like this with simulation. Here's [a related post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/226000/7071) about how to deal with this.